# Telegram Bot API method (getUserProfilePhotos)

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I am using this Telegram Bot API for NodeJS https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api    and there is a method "getUserProfilePhotos", I used it and got error:

```
"Bad Request: there is no photo in the request"
```

Here is my code

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var token = '********************************************';
var bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', function (msg) {
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    var userId = msg.from.id;

    bot.sendMessage(chatId,"There is something");   
    bot.sendPhoto(chatId,bot.getUserProfilePhotos(userId, 1, 1) ,{caption: "It's your photo!"});    

});
```

I have a Profile Photo in my telegram accaunt. I dont know what to do. Can someone help me? Sorry for my eng)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arrays Base Index Number is 0**

But you use 1 and 1! in this line:

`bot.sendPhoto(chatId,bot.getUserProfilePhotos(userId, 1, 1) ,{caption: "It's your photo!"});`

Correct it to :
`bot.sendPhoto(chatId,bot.getUserProfilePhotos(userId, 0, 0) ,{caption: "It's your photo!"});`

Comment: I have similar issue with Telegram Bot API, Could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806530/telegram-bot-api-server-down-when-use-getuserprofilephotos

Answer (score 2):

try this, work correctly:

```
bot.onText(/\/testuserphoto$/, function onMessage(msg) {
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    var userId = msg.from.id;

    bot.getUserProfilePhotos(userId, 0, 1).then(function(data){
      bot.sendPhoto(chatId,data.photos[0][0].file_id,{caption: "It's your photo!"});
    });

});
```

[getUserProfilePhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getuserprofilephotos) returns an [UserProfilePhotos](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#userprofilephotos) with *photos* attribute containing the list of user profile. Beside *getUserProfilePhoto* method want as second parameter photo id not photo object.

Comment: Could you help me for the similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806530/telegram-bot-api-server-down-when-use-getuserprofilephotos